# print() output in the GUI screen

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am hoping someone can help me.

Basically, I have an arbitrary script,  in this script, there are many functions and after each function is executed, print() is executed as well to give me an update. I'm using the Pysimplegui library for GUI, and was wondering if someone can help or explain what I can do to show the print output in the GUI

Comment: Word of caution should be added here..... if  `print` is called from a thread and the stdout has been rerouted to output in a PySimpleGUI window, then the odds are very high that the program will crash.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this that are in the documentation, here is one way.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# This is the normal print that comes with simple GUI
sg.Print('Re-routing the stdout', do_not_reroute_stdout=False)

# this is clobbering the print command, and replacing it with sg's Print()
print = sg.Print

# this will now output to the sg display.
print('This is a normal print that has been re-routed.')
```

Here is the example output

[image]

Comment: Hi nycynik, thank you for your answer, this was indeed in the documentation.

Comment: Glad it helps, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

you can utilize Multiline object and it's method `Multiline.print` then just monkey patch it like this:

```py
print = Multiline.print
```

ready window looks like this:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

logwindow = sg.Multiline(size=(70, 20), font=('Courier', 10))
print = logwindow.print
layout = [[logwindow]]

# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout, finalize=True)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=1)
    for i in range(100):
        print(f'print {i}')
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you are going to use any library, first read the docs.
I am sure you can find your answer.
https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Hello Mani Faridi, I hope you are doing well, I was not able to find an answer to my question in the documentation along with the cookbook.

Comment: @AlexeyPodoynitsyn Thanks. Actually, I haven't worked with this library. But looks like nycynik answered your question.

Comment: Right instincts. There's a section in the Cookbook on "printing" https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/cookbook/#recipe-printing